# How to set proxy for axios or fetch in Client side React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, proxy, fetch, axios

How to set porxy using for axios or fetch in Client side React(javascript).

Tried a lot of solutions but all fail to load the api. 
Tired axios-proxy-fix as well.

For a confirmation - The api works with Chrome CORS and Switchy proxy extention.

No Webpack-

Given ip and host e.g. x.x.x.x:xx

```
{
  "name": "testapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://X.X.X.X:X",
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "jest": "^19.0.2",
    "material-ui": "^0.17.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^v4.0.1",
    "pushstate-server": "^3.0.0",
    "react-cookie": "^1.0.5",
    "react-scripts": "0.9.0",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "axios-proxy-fix": "^0.16.3",
    "es6-promise": "^4.1.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.4.2",
    "react-addons-transition-group": "^15.4.2",
    "reactstrap": "^4.2.0",
    "tracer": "^0.8.7",
    "treeview-react-bootstrap": "^0.4.6",
    "tunnel": "0.0.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build-css": "node-sass src/ -o src/",
    "watch-css": "nodemon -e scss -x \"npm run build-css\"",
    "start-js": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
    "build": "npm run build-css && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

And Component

```
  import axios from 'axios-proxy-fix';
    //OR 
    import axios from 'axios';

/*********
The not writing rest of component stuff only axios part 
***********/
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: '/api/some-endpoint',
      baseURL: "the-base-url",
      headers: {
        'httpAgent': 'new http.Agent({ keepAlive: true })',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',        
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Proxy-Connection": "keep-alive"
      },
      proxy: {
        host: 'X.X.X.X',
        port: '80'
      }      
    })
      .then(res => {
        alert("ajax-respo-world");
        const posts = res.data.data;
        this.setState({ posts });
      }).catch(err => console.log("ajax-err", err))
   }
```

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. There's Axios `proxy` option that is used. What doesn't work? Why did you use axios-proxy-fix and what did make you think that it's needed?

Comment: First I tried with axios. It did not work. Over search I found that proxy is not supported in all the axios versions, so found axios-proxy-fix as a solution.

Comment: The question cannot be answered because it's unclear what the problem is. There's `proxy` option and it's expected to work. If you have problems connecting to a proxy, they could be specific to a proxy and not anything else.

Comment: that is why I mentioned that using chrome extensions (switchy proxy and CORS) it  returns a successful response.

Comment: This could be anything. It's hard to suggest anything specific without knowing the details. Unless you wish to provide a proxy and API entry point in the question, you're on your own with the problem. Notice that according to SO rules, code-related questions should contain a way to replicate the problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: That's true but can't expose the proxy/api, Can anyone suggest me to have/create dummy proxy based api ?

Comment: Try to test the app with local proxy, https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxy . It can be started from command line. You can set up local API with Express if needed . If the problem persists at this point, you can share the whole thing in the question then.

Comment: It tried with one of the proxy on https://www.proxynova.com/proxy-server-list/port-8080/ (opened using different ISP)
and  tried to request  one of the blocked sites on my network(another ISP). 
It didn't work

Comment: @estus can you please suggest? Given an api(http://example.com/users) with IP and port what should be a webpack dev server config for react ?

Comment: Just noticed that you're talking about *client-side*. Of course, you won't be able to do this. Not with Axios, not with anything else. If you need to do a request through a proxy, do it on server side. Notice that Axios proxy example is clearly specific to Node, https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config . `proxy` option will be ignored in browser.

Comment: Yes just found out there seems to be no option to handle this in client. And you confirmed it. I made it work through the node. Still searching to make it through Client.
Thanks J

Comment: Glad you clarified this. You can't make it through client because a browser doesn't expose such API. The only way would be anonymizer proxy url like `http://some-anonymizer.com/http://some-url.com...` which is not HTTP proxy but a different beast.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the conversation above is pretty much clear to conclude the answer that making an api call with a proxy is possible from *server* not from *client*.